# Using PowerShell how to create a file with unique data on each LBA

Tags: powershell, unique

On a Windows system, I have been trying to create a binary file with unique data on each LBA(512 bytes) using PowerShell - tried with [io.file]::WriteAllBytes, Get-Random,  Get-Unique command etc.

Kindly help.

Regards
Susanta

Answer (score 1):

Create a random byte array of e.g. 512 bytes in size:

```
$bytes = 1..512|%{[byte](Get-Random -Minimum ([byte]::MinValue) -Maximum ([byte]::MaxValue))}
```

Write the bytes to a file (with byte-encoding)

```
Set-Content -Path C:\tmp\test.random.txt -Value $bytes -Encoding Byte
```

Of course, you can adjust the byte max / min values if there's another range of values that you'd like in the random data. I added Max / Min Value for the byte type to examplify the range.